# JBOSS Basic authentication by remote IP addr

Tags: security, jboss

Is it possible to set up Basic Authentication on JBoss 5 AS for requests
coming in from a specific IP addr?

We have an internal development site that can also be accessed externally through
a proxy server. I'd only like to authenticate those coming from the proxy.

I had no problem setting up the Basic Authentication part. I just need to know how to 
do the IP check.

Any help would be appreciated.